# Thymeleaf. Renderizar texto con etiquetas HTML en HTML

Tags: html, html5, thymeleaf

Estoy usando *TINYMCE* para que en un formulario con un textarea el usuario pueda darle algunos estilos al texto. De esta forma en mi base de datos este campo se guarda, por ejemplo, de la siguiente manera.

```
<p><strong>Some description goes here...</strong></p>
```

El tema es que al mostrarlo en una pagina se ve asi tal cual, y lo que yo necesito es que no se vean las etiquetas y se vea el texto formateado/renderizado como aqui

**Some description goes here...**

He probado con las etiquetas `<pre>` y `<code>` pero no me dan los resultados que necesito.

Estoy usando Thymeleaf con Spring framework. En el IDE estoy intentando mostrar la descripcion e la siguiente forma

```
<article th:text="${product.description}"></article>
```

Gracias desde ya.

Comment: con que lenguaje lo traes de la base de datos? podes confirmar que se guarda `<p>` y no `&lt;p&gt;` ?

Comment: Si las etiquetas se están guardando de esa manera deberían de estarse mostrando correctamente, verifica que no se hayan formateado las etiquetas como indica @alo Malbarez

Comment: No se han formateado. Estan tal cual como pongo en el ejemplo, se guarda <p> , <strong>, etc

Comment: con qué lenguaje lo imprimis en el html? pon esa parte de código y podemos ver de ayudar en la transformación (puede que en algún punto entre la BD y el render se transformen a entidades html)

Comment: @aloMalbarez. He editado mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba imprimiendo con el `unescaped text`, algo asi:

```
<article th:utext="${product.description}"></article>
```

`th:text` sería el que te está convirtiendo los `tags` a `entities`

ref.
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text

Comment: Muchas gracias!